# Superset iframe login redirect

Tags: python, flask, iframe, apache-superset

I'm trying to understand how one should be able to insert Superset's dashboards and charts inside another application. At the moment I am at this step: I have inserted the iframe of a chart inside my html page and I am presented with Superset login page; after I insert the credentials I am redirected again on the login page, without ever seeing the chart. What am I doing wrong ? Am I missing part of the picture here ?

Here's my `superset_config.py`

```
import logging
import os

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="mysql+pymysql://superset:superset@127.0.0.1:3306/superset"

REDIS_HOST="localhost"
REDIS_PORT=6379

# Will allow user self registration, allowing to create Flask users from Authorized User
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

# The default user self registration role
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Public"

# Flask-WTF flag for CSRF
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
```

And here's the basic html page I built with the iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>iframe integration</h1>

<iframe
  width="800"
  height="800"
  seamless
  frameBorder="0"
  scrolling="yes"
  src="http://<remote server hostname>:8088/superset/explore/?r=2&standalone=true&height=400"
>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

When I enter the html page from Firefox I see the login page, like in the picture below

[image]

When I insert the credentials I am redirected to the same login page.

This is what I see from Superset's logs

```
INFO:werkzeug:<my ip>- - [07/Apr/2021 13:12:07] "POST /login/?next=http%3A%2F%2F<remote server hostname>%3A8088%2Fsuperset%2Fexplore%2F%3Fr%3D2%26standalone%3Dtrue%26height%3D400 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO:werkzeug:<my ip> - - [07/Apr/2021 13:12:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO:werkzeug:<my ip> - - [07/Apr/2021 13:12:07] "GET /superset/welcome HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO:werkzeug:<my ip> - - [07/Apr/2021 13:12:07] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your app and your superset is not severed under the same domain name.

You will need to:

1. add `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'` in `superset_config.py`
2. make sure setup firefox is configured to not block cross-site cookies (this is not recommended but it will make embedded chart).

So the redirect from `/superset/welcome` to `/login/` means superset can not find your session from cookie (your browser may block 3rd party cookie since superset is served as 3rd party)

If you're serving superset over HTTP instead of HTTPS, you will need `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False` in `superset_config.py` as well although it's not recommended to use http only.

**Notice**: this solution works for Firefox and Chrome/Chromium, but not Safari.

Comment: I added what you are saying but I couldn't access data without login, the login form keeps appearing, any suggestion?

Comment: I tried all the solutions mentioned in the above answer but still getting redirected to login page, any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had faced same issue, Got solved when the DOMAIN names matched with my superset and application host.,

that is, i was running superset in AWS machine with domain name : http://superset.domainName.com., and was trying to render the IFRAME from angular application in local [http://localhost:4433]

the superset window would load and always points to LOGIN page of superset.

once i moved my angular application to same domain [http://app.domainName.com], the angular application was able to render dashboard and charts.

Key points :

- Both application and superset has to have same either http or https
- Both application and superset has to have same domain